# creating a contingency table in booktabs-look

Tags: tables, rules, booktabs, threeparttable

How to format the rules of a contingency table?

The table should still fit the look of my other tables, which are created with the booktabs package.

I'm using the booktabs package and normally following the rule to not use vertical rules, but in this case I need one.

Here is my code using one midrule and one vertical rule:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{name}
\begin{tabular}{c|ccccccc}
\toprule
  & B & C & D & E & F & G & H\\
\midrule
A & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
B &   & 9 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
C &   &   & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\
D &   &   &   & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
E &   &   &   &   & 4 & 5 & 6\\
F &   &   &   &   &   & 7 & 8\\
G &   &   &   &   &   &   & 9\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
\item[] notes
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two other possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{boldline, cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{1.5ex}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{1.3ex}
\renewcommand\TPTtagStyle{\itshape}

%% Define a few struts
%% (from code by Claudio Beccari in TeX and TUG News, Vol. 2, 1993)
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.7ex}} % "top" strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-1.1ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % "bottom" strut
\newcommand\TBstrut{\Tstrut\Bstrut} % "top and bottom" strut

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Name}
    \begin{tabular}{cV{3}*{7}{Sc}V{1.8}}
                 & B\tnote{a} & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
      \hlineB{3}
      A & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
      B & & 9 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
      C & & & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
      D & & & & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
      E & & & & & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
      F & & & & & & 7 & 8 \\
      G\tnote{b} & & & & & & & 9 \\
      \clineB{1-8}{1.8}
    \end{tabular}
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item[a] The letter ``B'' is very important.
      \item[b] So is the letter ``G''.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Name}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{Gainsboro!50}}c!{\hspace{0.4em}}*{7}{Sc}|}
      \rowcolor{Gainsboro!50} \cellcolor{Yellow!60!OrangeRed!32! } & B\tnote{a} & C & D & E & F & G & \multicolumn{1}{c}{H} \\
      \noalign{\vspace{0.5ex}}
      A & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
      B & & 9 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
      C & & & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
      D & & & & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
      E & & & & & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
      F & & & & & & 7 & 8 \\
      G\tnote{b} & & & & & & & 9 \\
      \cline{2-8}
    \end{tabular}
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item[a] The letter ``B'' is very important.
      \item[b] So is the letter ``G''.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Update:*

I propose some improvements to the `tablenotes` part of the O.P.'s solution, using the `para`option (with a small patch):

```
\documentclass[preview, border={10pt 10pt -180pt 10pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{xpatch} 
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\TPT@doparanotes}{%
\hskip 1em\@plus .3em}{%
\hskip 0.75em\@plus .25em}
\makeatother

%% Define a few struts
%% (from code by Claudio Beccari in TeX and TUG News, Vol. 2, 1993)
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.7ex}} % "top" strut

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Name}
\begin{tabular}{c|*{7}{c}}
\toprule
  & B & C & D & E & F & G & H\\
\hline
A & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\Tstrut\\
B & & 9 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
C & & & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\
D & & & & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
E & & & & & 4 & 5 & 6\\
F & & & & & & 7 & 8\\
G & & & & & & & 9\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[para, online]\footnotesize%
\def\tnote#1{\protect\TPToverlap{\TPTtagStyle{#1}}}%
\item[A]--- Apple, 
\item[B]--- Banana, 
\item[C]--- Cherry, 
\item[D]--- Date, 
\item[E]--- Elderberry, 
\item[F]--- Fig, 
\item[G]--- Grape, 
\item[H]--- Honeydew melon. 
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Since vertical rules appear to be a necessity, I suggest you *not* use the macros of the `booktabs` package. To get adequate spacing above and below the horizontal rules created by `\hline`, I suggest you insert typographic struts, as is done in the following example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\renewcommand\TPTtagStyle{\itshape}

%% Define a few struts
%% (from code by Claudio Beccari in TeX and TUG News, Vol. 2, 1993)
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.7ex}} % "top" strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-1.1ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % "bottom" strut
\newcommand\TBstrut{\Tstrut\Bstrut}   % "top and bottom" strut

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Name}
\begin{tabular}{|c|ccccccc|}
\hline
  & B\tnote{a} & C & D & E & F & G & H\TBstrut\\
\hline
A & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\Tstrut\\
B &   & 9 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
C &   &   & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\
D &   &   &   & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
E &   &   &   &   & 4 & 5 & 6\\
F &   &   &   &   &   & 7 & 8\\
G\tnote{b} &   &   &   &   &   &   & 9\Bstrut\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] The letter ``B'' is very important.
\item[b] So is the letter ``G''.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm providing an own answer, using code that Mico and Bernard came of with.

I think this formatting looks nice, especially when it's used with other tables in booktabs-threeparttable-layout.

PS: I'm unsure, if the spacing is nice at every point.

```
\documentclass[preview, border={10pt 10pt -180pt 10pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

%% Define a few struts
%% (from code by Claudio Beccari in TeX and TUG News, Vol. 2, 1993)
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.7ex}} % "top" strut

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Name}
\begin{tabular}{c|ccccccc}
\toprule
  & B & C & D & E & F & G & H\\
\hline
A & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\Tstrut\\
B &   & 9 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
C &   &   & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\
D &   &   &   & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
E &   &   &   &   & 4 & 5 & 6\\
F &   &   &   &   &   & 7 & 8\\
G &   &   &   &   &   &   & 9\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
\item[] A --- Apple, B --- Banana, C --- Cherry, D --- Date, E --- Elderberry, F --- Fig, G --- Grape, H --- Honeydew melon
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: contingency table]

Comment: Nice, but I propose an improvement to the tablenotes part, based on the `para`  option, so the notes are left-aligned. Please take a look at my  updated answer.